# I'm trying to get chrome extension to get tags in iframe across origins

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build chrome extension to get tags in iframe across origins, but it shows `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://aaa.xxx.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`
For example, I'm on the site "https://aaa.xxx.com" want to get a iframe tag in "https://bbb.xxx.com"(Same primary domain name.)
Which page should I add code to make it run? Thanks.

Comment: Different hosts violate the origin policy. For an explanation how an origin is defined, take a look at [MDN: Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin).

Comment: I get it, but I want to get a tag even pages use different hostnames.